# can't find my new attribute with dynamic options

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, swatches

when i access to stores product my new attribute i found this :
[image]

ok this is my code to install the new attribute

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{

    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'choix_prix_product');
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'choix_prix_product',/* Custom Attribute Code */
        [
            'type' => 'text',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Choix-Prix de vente', /* lablel of your attribute*/
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Mdweb\ConfigAttribute\Model\Config\Source\Options',
            /* Source of your select type custom attribute options*/
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            /*Scope of your attribute */
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false,
            'unique' => false
        ]
    );
}
```

}

and this is the source code :

```
 public function getAllOptions()
{

    $_product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

    $_sku = $_product->getSku();
    if (isset($_sku)){

    $var1 = substr($_sku, 0, 1);


    $var2 = substr($_sku, 1, 2);

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('table_prix');


    $fields = array('prix_unitaire');


    $sql = $connection->select()
        ->from($tableName, $fields)
        ->where('code_famille' . '=?', $var1)
        ->where('code_nom_commercial' . '=?', $var2)
        ->join('table_choix',
            'table_choix.choix_id = table_prix.code_choix',
            [
                'designation_choix'
            ]);

    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

    if ($result) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($result as $elt) {
            $this->_options[$i] = ['label' => " Choix" . $elt['designation_choix'] . "-" . $elt['prix_unitaire'] . "£", 'value' => " Choix" . $elt['designation_choix'] . "-" . $elt['prix_unitaire'] . "£"];
            $i++;
        }


    }   }else{
        $this->_options = [
            ['label' => __(''), 'value' =>'' ]];

    }


    return  $this->_options;


}
```

the idea is to create a product then return to this product and make it configurable according to the options of the  new attribute if there is no options so my product is simple 
i can see my new product [image]

but when i access the attribute details i find the screenshot that i put in first time 
I waited to find my new attribute like others so what's the problem any help please

Comment: can you add more steps what you doing? where do you go??

Comment: to little explanation for understanding

Comment: i will put the code

Comment: I`m waiting,please do it

Comment: please check my updating answer

Comment: $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection'); this is a bad to use object manager!

Comment: so i should put create instead of get

Comment: did you do reindex ?

Comment: no i will do it now

Comment: do it , and check it , after write to me please

Comment: the message still there

Comment: use this please bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_attribute

Comment: ok i will  used it now

Comment: same message can't find the details of my new attribute

Comment: is there an error while creating my attribute

Comment: look, you create new attribute, but 'source' => 'Mdweb\ConfigAttribute\Model\Config\Source\Options', should be use for getting options for your attribute select

Comment: public function getAllOptions()
{

Comment: yes but this attrbute will show options according to the product

Comment: add $this->_options = [
                ['label' => __('No'), 'value'=>'0'],
                ['label' => __('Yes'), 'value'=>'1'],
                ['label' => __('Other'), 'value'=>'2']
            ];
 
    return $this->_options;

Comment: in the else in getAlloptions function ??

Comment: no, comment your code in  getAlloptions() { ... } and add my example

Comment: re-run setup, and check your attribute, it will be ok

Comment: ok but i need dynamic options

Comment: yes i can access the detailed  attribute info but i need to have dynamic options and not static

Comment: just for test do it

Comment: check this line  $this->_options[$i]

Comment: edit it $this->_options = ['label' =>....

Comment: delete index ($i) , just put $this->_options =

Comment: this to recuperate all my options from the result

Comment: do it please , and check

Comment: if i delet it i will jut recuperate the last value becuase he will delete the first

Comment: ok i will check that

Comment: i  lost the detailed page now i returned to the message  is default swatch default store view

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93332/discussion-on-question-by-developper-magento-cant-find-my-new-attribute-with-d).